# Accessing values of object using "this"

Tags: javascript

I have this code with me,

```
var x = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: (this.a + this.b)
};
```

where `this.a` and `this.b` is coming as undefined. So as a result of adding the both and printing it displays `NaN`. Also I tried with `(x.a + x.b)`. The results were the same.

Can anyone tell how do I access a JSON object's value internally using `this`? May be other way?

Comment: you can't do like this if you want achieve you can make c as function :
var x = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: function(){  return (this.a + this.b); }
};
x.c();

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to `x` in this case, it refers to the global object.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will refer the linked question to know more. Actually I did not have the exact words to frame a search query for this problem.

Comment: @SundarSingh Thanks sundar. That may be a good idea to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to using the same object value in JSon using "this"

```
 var x = {
   a: 10,
   b: 20,
   c: function(){return (this.a + this.b)}
 };
 console.log(x.c())
```

Comment: that's not what he's trying to achieve

Comment: @littlepootis But this may be an alternate solution to that. This is helpful.